# Is there a correct way to determine that an NSNumber is derived from a Bool using Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsnumber

An NSNumber containing a Bool is easily confused with other types that can be wrapped in the NSNumber class:

```
NSNumber(bool:true).boolValue // true
NSNumber(integer: 1).boolValue // true
NSNumber(integer: 1) as? Bool // true
NSNumber(bool:true) as? Int // 1

NSNumber(bool:true).isEqualToNumber(1) // true
NSNumber(integer: 1).isEqualToNumber(true) // true
```

However, information about its original type is retained, as we can see here:

```
NSNumber(bool:true).objCType.memory == 99 // true
NSNumber(bool:true).dynamicType.className() == "__NSCFBoolean" // true
NSNumber(bool:true).isEqualToValue(true) || NSNumber(bool:true).isEqualToValue(false) //true
```

The question is: which of these approaches is the best (and/or safest) approach to determining when a Bool has been wrapped within an NSNumber rather than something else? Are all equally valid? Or, is there another, better solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can ask the same question for Objective-C, and here is an answer in Objective-C - which you can call from, or translate into, Swift.

`NSNumber` is toll-free bridged to `CFNumberRef`, which is another way of saying an `NSNumber` object is in fact a `CFNumber` one (and vice-versa). Now `CFNumberRef` has a specific type for booleans, `CFBooleanRef`, and this is used when creating a boolean `CFNumberRef` aka `NSNumber *`... So all you need to do is check whether your `NSNumber *` is an instance of `CFBooleanRef`:

```
- (BOOL) isBoolNumber:(NSNumber *)num
{
   CFTypeID boolID = CFBooleanGetTypeID(); // the type ID of CFBoolean
   CFTypeID numID = CFGetTypeID((__bridge CFTypeRef)(num)); // the type ID of num
   return numID == boolID;
}
```

*Note:* You may notice that `NSNumber`/`CFNumber` objects created from booleans are actually pre-defined constant objects; one for `YES`, one for `NO`. You may be tempted to rely on this for identification. However, though is currently appears to be true, and is shown in [Apple's source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/CFNumber.c), to our knowledge it is **not documented** so should not be relied upon.

HTH

**Addendum**

Swift code translation (by GoodbyeStackOverflow):

```
func isBoolNumber(num:NSNumber) -> Bool
{
    let boolID = CFBooleanGetTypeID() // the type ID of CFBoolean
    let numID = CFGetTypeID(num) // the type ID of num
    return numID == boolID
}
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer as you've provided a working solution. Since it's not in Swift, I've edited your response to include the Swift code (just waiting for the peer review of that edit). Thanks.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow - approved your translation for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the correct one.

`NSNumber` is an Objective-C class. It is built for Objective-C. It stores the type using the type encodings of Objective-C. So in Objctive-C the best solution would be:

```
number.objCType[0] == @encoding(BOOL)[0] // or string compare, what is not necessary here
```

This ensures that a change of the type encoding will work after re-compile.

AFAIK you do not have `@encoding()` in Swift. So you have to use a literal. However, this will not break, because `@encoding()` is replaced at compile time and changing the encodings would break with compiled code. Unlikely.

The second approach uses a internal identifier. This is likely subject of change.

I think the third approach will have false positives.

Comment: The problem is that `@encode(BOOL)` and `@encode(signed char)` and `@encode(char)` all return `c` / `99`, (provided `-funsigned-char` was not given to the compiler).

Comment: This is a property of `NSNumber` that cannot be changed. And I do not see a problem with that.

Comment: Because OP specifically asked about determining whether an `NSNumber` is wrapping a `BOOL` object *rather than something else*.

Comment: Yes, but look at his third solution. `BOOL`'s have been chars for a long time without problems. Both are still integers. I do not think that this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the class name as it likely belongs to a class cluster, and it is an implementation detail (and therefore subject to change).

Unfortunately, the Objective-C `BOOL` type was originally a just typedef for a `signed char` in C, which is always encoded as `c` (this is the `99` value you are seeing, since `c` in ASCII is 99).

In modern Objective-C, I believe the `BOOL` type is an actual Boolean type (i.e. no longer just a typedef for `signed char`) but for compatibility, it still encodes as `c` when given to `@encode()`.

So, there's no way to tell whether the `99` originally referred to a `signed char` or a `BOOL`, as far as `NSNumber` is concerned they are the same.

Maybe if you explain why you need to know whether the `NSNumber` was originally a `BOOL`, there may be a better solution.

Comment: The reason is because when using NSJSONSerialization Bools are imported as NSNumber instances and I need to distinguish between these to deal with JSON in a type safe manner, e.g. only allowing a Bool to change to true or false not 10 or 100, or 999.99, and to also make sure they are transformed back to true and false not 1 and 0 in exported JSON.

Comment: When transforming back to JSON, call `-boolValue` on the `NSNumber` to get a 1 or a 0.

Comment: As I understand it from the documentation, boolValue simply provides a bool interpretation of any NSNumber instance: "A 0 value always means false, and any nonzero value is interpreted as true." But I want to maintain the true/false representation and not confuse bools and numbers.