# Determine that `true` is a Bool and not a number equal to 1

Tags: swift

*Title is sub-optimal, suggestions welcome*

Ran into a little trouble with `Bool` and numeric values. I want to determine if an `AnyObject` (from a JSON) is a `Bool` or a number.

So I need a test that will only succeed if the inserted type was truly a `Bool` or a number. Now it automatically converts and all statements are true.

```
let some : AnyObject = 1

if some is Bool {
    print("is Bool", some as! Bool)
}

if some is Int {
    print("is Int", some as! Int)
}

let some2 : AnyObject = false

if some2 is Bool {
    print("is Bool", some2 as! Bool)
}

if some2 is Int {
    print("is Int", some2 as! Int)
}

let some3 : AnyObject = 1.1

if some3 is Bool {
    print("is Bool", some3 as! Bool)
}

if some3 is Int {
    print("is Int", some3 as! Int)
}
```

Comment: Do "numeric values" include float/double?

Comment: What's the context of this? Doesn't whatever JSON lib your using already do this conversion?

Comment: @AMomchilov apparently this is also true for float/double

Comment: @AMomchilov not using any JSON libs, I am working on a code generator that writes a Model based on a JSON. Type inference is done based on the value for a specific key.

Comment: Well the next obvious question is: why aren't you using a JSON lib?

Comment: @AMomchilov because much can be learned from trying things like this. My question is clearly not: "I have trouble with JSON", It is: "How do I circumvent this behaviour in Swift?"

Comment: @MartinR you are right, same question, but vadian's answer is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1`, `1.0`, `true`, all types are bridged to `NSNumber`

You can check the `objCType`

```
let some : AnyObject = true

if let type = String.fromCString(some.objCType) {
  switch type {
  case "c" : print("is Bool", some as! Bool)
  case "q" : print("is Int", some as! Int)
  case "d" : print("is Double", some as! Double)
  default :  print("no idea")
  }
} else {
  print("no matching objCType")
}
```

Source: [Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

Comment: Perfect, I feared there was no way to do this.

Comment: Just because you **can** doesn't mean you **should**. You'd be better off reworking this to use Generics, or at least `Any`. (Unlike `AnyObject`, primitives can be used with `Any` without bridging to NSNumber)

Comment: @AMomchilov well I don't believe my experiments with JSON -> Swift Model with have far reaching real world effects.....

Comment: This will detect `NSNumber(char: 65)` as a boolean ...

Comment: I'm not saying they will, but this is just bad stuff to base your learning off anyway. You're bridging from Swift to Objective C, bridging to C to get a C string, then converting it back into a Swift String just to switch on it to do forced casting. This is gross.

Comment: I haven't done much testing, but this *seems* to work better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30223989/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, of course, but I guess the purpose of the question is to get the numeric type out of JSON

Comment: @vadian that is true, the code above a just a mock

Comment: @MartinR Yes, much better, but even still, this problem should be addressed at the root cause. This wouldn't be necessary if the source of the `AnyObject` was designed properly.

Comment: @AMomchilov show me a way to receive data from a remote source as native Swift types and I will take it!

Comment: On 32-bit platforms, `Int` would be encoded as "i", not "q".

Comment: @MartinR All my tests just passed, thank you!