# How to check the NSNumber is boolean or int32?

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, nsnumber, int32

I have declared one variable as `NSNumber` and assigned `bool true`. Then I have declared another `NSNumber` and assigned int 1.

When I try to retrieve the datatype of both variables, both returns as Int. This issue happened only in iPhone 5 and lower which is 32bit architecture.

How to resolve this issue?

```
var number: NSNumber = 1
var boolienValue: NSNumber = true

func getType(value: AnyObject) -> String? {

    if value is Int {
        return "Int"
    } else if value is Bool {
        return = "Bool"
    }
    else if value is Double {

        return = "Double"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine that `true` is a Bool and not a number equal to 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597619/determine-that-true-is-a-bool-and-not-a-number-equal-to-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a correct way to determine that an NSNumber is derived from a Bool using Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215680/is-there-a-correct-way-to-determine-that-an-nsnumber-is-derived-from-a-bool-usin)