# Cannot differenciat double and int from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have one dictionary which has different data type value from that dictionary i create insert query for database now my problem is if i pass double value then also it goes in Int condition if i write Int condition up and Int condition down. I also try with **isKind(of:)** but same thing happened.

> Here is my code with **as** keyword

```
     //MARK: INSERT RECORDS
        func insertRecord(_ dictRecord : NSDictionary, tableName : String)->Bool
        {

            //Example:- INSERT INTO subject(sub_color,sub_name,sub_priority)values(125.562000,'Maths','15')

            let strStart = "INSERT INTO " + tableName
            var column : String = "("
            var values : String = "("

            var i = 0
            for key in dictRecord.allKeys
            {
                column = (column as String) + (key as! String) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
    //            column = "\(column) \(key) \(condition)" as NSString


                if let strValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? String
                {
                    values = (values as String) + "\"" + strValue + "\"" + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
    //                values = "\(values)'\(strValue)' \(condition) " as NSString

                }else if let doubleValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Double
                {
                    values = (values as String)  + String (format: "%f",doubleValue) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
    //                   let strDoubleValue = String(format: "%f", doubleValue)
    //                 values = "\(values) \(strDoubleValue) \(condition) " as NSString


                }else if let numValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Int
                {
                    values = (values as String)  + String (format: "%d",numValue) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
    //                let strNumValue = String(format: "%d", numValue)
    //                values = "\(values) \(strNumValue) \(condition) " as NSString


                }
                 i = i + 1
            }
    //        column = (column as String) + ")"
    //        values = (values as String) + ")"
                column = "\(column))"
                values = "\(values))"
            let strQuery = String(format:"%@%@values%@",strStart,column,values)
            return self.executeQuery(strQuery)
        }
```

> My code with **is** code

```
func insertRecord(_ dictRecord : NSDictionary, tableName : String)->Bool
    {
        //Example:- INSERT INTO subject(sub_color,sub_name,sub_priority)values(125.562000,'Maths','15')
        let strStart = "INSERT INTO " + tableName
        var column : String = "("
        var values : String = "("
        var i = 0
        for key in dictRecord.allKeys
        {
            column = (column as String) + (key as! String) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
            //            column = "\(column) \(key) \(condition)" as NSString
            if let strValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? String
            {
                values = (values as String) + "\"" + strValue + "\"" + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
                //                values = "\(values)'\(strValue)' \(condition) " as NSString
            }else if dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) is Int
            {
                let numValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Int
                values = (values as String)  + String (format: "%d",numValue!) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
                //                let strNumValue = String(format: "%d", numValue)
                //                values = "\(values) \(strNumValue) \(condition) " as NSString
            }else if dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) is Double
            {
                let doubleValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Double
                values = (values as String)  + String (format: "%f",doubleValue!) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
                //                   let strDoubleValue = String(format: "%f", doubleValue)
                //                 values = "\(values) \(strDoubleValue) \(condition) " as NSString
            }else if dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) is Float
            {
                let floatValue = dictRecord.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Float
                values = (values as String)  + String (format: "%f",floatValue!) + ((dictRecord.allKeys.count-1 == i) ? "" : ",")
                //                   let strDoubleValue = String(format: "%f", doubleValue)
                //                 values = "\(values) \(strDoubleValue) \(condition) " as NSString
            }
            i = i + 1
        }
        //        column = (column as String) + ")"
        column = "\(column))"
        values = "\(values))"
        let strQuery = String(format:"%@%@values%@",strStart,column,values)
        return self.executeQuery(strQuery)
    }
```

What i try to store

```
{
"country_Lat" = "112.00";
"country_Long" = 112122.000; // if always store in database like 112122
"country_Name" = London;
"country_Status" = 1;
"country_id" = 2;
createddate = "12:00";
updateddate = "1:00";
}
```

Comment: If you want to live a happier life as a Swift coder, stop using NSDictionary right now, and use Swift dictionaries. They are typed and safe. One shouldn't do things like `.value(forKey: (key as! String)) as? Double` in Swift. Just use subscript on properly typed Swift arrays or dictionaries.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a correct way to determine that an NSNumber is derived from a Bool using Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215680/is-there-a-correct-way-to-determine-that-an-nsnumber-is-derived-from-a-bool-usin).

Comment: @EricAya i try with your suggestion but same result

Comment: @chiragshah Ah, too bad. Well then I hope somebody will be able to help you. Anyway, as Price Ringo also says, "Maybe you are forced to use the Objective C types because of legacy code constraints. However embrace Swift types and programming idioms wherever you can." Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I avoid `Any` typed dictionaries whenever I can, but if your keys are `String` and you use common value types, your code can be greatly simplified if you follow Eric Aya's advice.  Here is the equivalent `insertRecord` function.

```
func insertRecord(_ dictionary: [String: Any], tableName: String) -> Bool {
  let columns = dictionary.keys.joined(separator: ",")
  let values = dictionary.values.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ",")
  return self.executeQuery("INSERT INTO \(tableName)(\(columns))values(\(values))")
}
```

[image]

Maybe you are forced to use the Objective C types because of legacy code constraints. However embrace Swift types and programming idioms wherever you can.

Comment: thank you for answer but in code we can made a insert query like you made in database i put the double value for location which always store int and if i write double condition ahead then my country_id become float and whole database display wrong value